# Microsoft Graph to access only a specific set of users, not all

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have a big organization spread across different locations and some of them want to grant permissions for applications in Azure AD which request access to read and manage email data. Is there any way to only allow the application to access a specific set of users based on a security group or attribute?

Now the application gets access to "Read and write mail in all mailboxes" which is a big security concerns for our organization.

[Screenshot for application API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rhEd.png)

Comment: Have you checked this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: You can do this through PowerShell, lease see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018228/13682781

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, microsoft graph application permissions can't be limited, it is for the entire tenant. But we can use [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps) command as juunas suggested to restrict your app to target mailboxes.

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "{appID}" -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com -Description "Restrict this app to members of security group EvenUsers."
```

To create a mail-enabled security group, you can login this [page](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/) and refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mail-enabled-security-groups?view=exchserver-2019#create-mail-enabled-security-groups). Put the specific set of users into the security group, then your app will only be granted access to the data of the specific set of users.