# How to limit Microsoft Graph permissions for an Azure app registration?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm struggling to find out how to limit the permissions of an Azure app registration to call the Microsoft Graph APIs (for example to send emails). The email in this case must be sent in an unattended scenario (no user present) by an application.

To call Microsoft Graph APIs, consent must be granted for the entire organization by a Global Application Administrator. This is often a huge ask for an admin to consent to an app being able to send emails on behalf of *any* user in the entire org!

Is there a way to setup an app registration to be able to send emails by an application for *only a specific email address*? For example, can the app be allowed to send emails as *my-no-reply-email-address@myorg.com* (unattended without a user), but not as any other user in the organization?

In order words, **how can we setup an app registration to send emails through the Microsoft Graph API only as a particular user (i.e. service account) without needed to grant the app permissions to send emails on behalf of any user in the entire organization?** Is this possible?

Comment: You need to setup scoping https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access for your app

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible trough the online portal right now, but you can do it trough PowerShell.

•   Create a group

1. Goto portal.office365.com and connect with Admin account
2. Goto https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/groups and click on tab [Mail-enabled security]
3. Click on [Add a group]
4. Select [Mail-enabled security] then click Next
5. Set a name and click Next
6. Set group name and select [Approval] which mean (Require owner approval to join the group)
7. Then Next, then create.

•   Add emails to group

1. Goto https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/#/groups and click on tab [Mail-enabled security]
2. Click on the group and add emails you want to allow APIs to access

•   PowerShell

1. Run PowerShell
2. Run: Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
3. Run: Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
4. Run: Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force
5. Run: Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
6. Run: Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName {ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE}
7. Sign in as Admin in pop-up window
8. Run: New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId {APPLICATION_ID_HERE} -PolicyScopeGroupId {GROUP_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE} -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE."

•   Test

1. In the same PowerShell..
2. Run: Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity {AN_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE} -AppId {APPLICATION_ID_HERE}
3. See AccessCheckResult, should be Granted or Denied

Answer (score 0):

As @Glen Scales commented,This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) can meet your needs.

> Administrators who want to limit the app access to a specific set of
> mailboxes can use the New-ApplicationAccessPolicy PowerShell cmdlet to
> configure access control. This article covers the basic steps to
> configure an application access policy.
>
> ***These steps are specific to Exchange Online resources and do not apply
> to other Microsoft Graph workloads.***