# MS Graph Permissions for Adding a OAuth Client Secret are Too Broad

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am following the example on this page to use powershell to create a client secret for my Azure AD application: https://o365info.com/create-unlimited-client-secret/

It starts out with this command:

`Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Application.ReadWrite.All'`

This gives me a login window that is requesting permissions to read and write to ALL applications.

I don't have permissions to (nor do I want permissions to) all of my companies applications.  I just need to add a client secret to the one application that I have permissions for.

So I figure, "fine, I will find the way to just request the scope for my one application."  But when I look up the [help for my command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/add-mgapplicationpassword?view=graph-powershell-1.0) (`Add-MgApplicationPassword`), both of the examples also ask for `Application.ReadWrite.All`.

It seems crazy that the only way I can modify one application is if I am granted permissions to modify ALL applications in my company's Azure Active Directory.

**How can I call `Add-MgApplicationPassword`, but only have permissions to one application?**

(NOTE: I can add these via the UI, but I need to be able to automate it via PowerShell.)

Comment: According to the docs for the add password API endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), for delegated access scenarios, the ReadWrite.All permission is the only one available. There is an option with application permissions though, using the OwnedBy version. This requires authenticating differently to PowerShell as your user account would not be involved at all.

Comment: @juunas - Thank you for the response.  Seems odd that I have permissions via the UI, but cannot find a way to do it via PowerShell.  But I will look into using OwnedBy to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: Microsoft Graph API permissions cannot be restricted to one application as it is granted for the entire tenant.

I agree with *@junnas*, as a workaround you can make use of Application API permissions "**`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`**" to connect to **MgGraph** with application context.

- By granting `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`  permission it allows to manage apps that this application creates or owns.
- By this API permission, it can create the applications and fully manage those applications (read, update, update application secrets and delete).
- But it will not be able to update the applications that it is not an owner of.

I created an **Azure AD Application and API permission** like below:

[image]

***Using the above application, I created another application:***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanTID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

I created the new application successfully:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type : application/json

{
"displayName": "ClientSecretApp"
}
```

[image]

I used the below **PowerShell script to add password** to the application:

```
$ApplicationId = "ClientID"
$tenantID = "TenantID"

Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $ApplicationId -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint "Thumbprint"

$passwordCred = @{
   displayName = 'testsecret'
   endDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMonths(6)
}

$secret = Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $ObjectIDoftheOwnedApplication -PasswordCredential $passwordCred
$secret | Format-List
```

**The Client Secret got created:**

[image]

In Azure Portal:

[image]

Now, when I passed the **ObjectID of the other application which is not owned**, I got the error like below:

[image]

**References:**

[azure - Microsoft Graph to access only a specific set of users, not all - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521474/microsoft-graph-to-access-only-a-specific-set-of-users-not-all) by Hury Shen

[Limit permissions to update a single Azure AD group via API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/905933/limit-permissions-to-update-a-single-azure-ad-grou) by ShivaniRai-MSFT

Comment: Wow!  I will see if I can make this work.  You are amazing for taking the time to put that together!  Thank you!

Comment: This worked spectacularly well!  Thank you very much!