# Insufficient Permissions 403 for Add-MgApplicationPassword Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

In an Azure Devops pipeline, I am trying to run a Azure Powershell script which would create an app registration and then generate a client secret for that created app.

The service principal behind the service connection running this script has "Application Developer" built in role.

Problem: The app registration gets created but the client secret generation fails saying "

```
Add-MgApplicationPassword_Add: /home/vsts/work/1/drop/pipelines/scripts/AppRegistrationDeployment.ps1:73
Line |
  73 |          Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $applicationId -Body …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.  Status: 403
     | (Forbidden) ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
```

The created app has the SPN running the script (the one behind the service connection) as the Owner, so I am unsure why does it fail with insufficient permissions.

This is how I connect to Microsoft graph

```
    Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

    $context = Get-AzContext
    $graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
    
    $secureGraphToken = $graphToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $secureGraphToken
```

this works

```
$createAppBody = @{
                displayName = $AppRegistrationName
            }
$appreg = New-MgApplication -BodyParameter $createAppBody
```

However this fails with insufficient permissions

```
$clientSecretBody = @{
            passwordCredential = @{
                displayName = "$secretNamePrefix-$secretSuffix"
                endDateTime = $secretEndDate
            }
        }
Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $applicationId -BodyParameter $clientSecretBody
```

As mentioned on the created app, I see the SPN running the script ( a service connection) as the Owner of the created app.

Why would an owner not be able to create a secret, when it can create the app itself?

Any questions and I can answer.

P.s I have already tried

```
Disconnect-MgGraph
```

and then try to re-initialize the token again but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occured as [**Application Developer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-developer) role does not have `microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update` permission to create credentials(secret) in it.

I assigned **Application Developer** role to the service principal named `SriGraphRole`:

[image]

When I ran below PowerShell commands to create application and secret in it, I too got **same error**:

```
$secureGraphToken = $graphToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $secureGraphToken
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

$app = New-MgApplication -DisplayName 'NewMGapp'
$params = @{
    PasswordCredential = @{
        DisplayName = "secret"
    }
}
Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $app.Id -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, your service principal should be assigned
> with either required **API permission** or Azure AD **directory role**
> having `microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update` action.

In my case, I assigned [**Application Administrator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator) role to the service principal named `SriGraphRole`:

[image]

When I ran below PowerShell script again, new application with secret created successfully like below:

```
$secureGraphToken = $graphToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $secureGraphToken
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

$app = New-MgApplication -DisplayName 'NewMGapp'
$params = @{
    PasswordCredential = @{
        DisplayName = "secret"
    }
}
Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $app.Id -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where new application with **secret** created:

[image]

When the **user** is added as **Owner** of application, he can create secrets without any extra permissions as Application Owner of **user** type has  `microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update` action access added by default as mentioned in this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#owned-application-registrations).

But same is not applicable for application scenario and it requires [`Application.ReadWrite.Ownedby`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-4:%7E:text=Manage%20apps%20that%20this%20app%20creates%20or%20owns) API permission that works only if service principal is **Owner** of application which is an in-built action.

Comment: That was a very good explanation. I was able to solve it as per my answer but wasn't clear on why the extra api permission was needed. Your answer clarified it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , though I do not understand why it needed that extra permission.

So, I had to give the App (running the script), API Permissions- highlighted in yellow

[image]

I do not understand why it needed, despite being an owner of the app , and also being a member of the built in role "Application Developer" . That is how it was able to create the app and become an owner of it (since it created the app).

If someone knows the reason, please feel free to post an explanation. Until then, for someone having the same problem, this is the solution.

this is the built in role it had before (and thus able to create the app)

[image]

Comment: It's because `Application Developer` role can only create applications or service principals and don't have access to create secrets or credentials. You can check that by clicking Description of that role like [this](https://i.imgur.com/b8xDaXH.png). If you want to create client secrets with Azure AD role, you can assign **Application Administrator** role to service principal that has required permission like [this](https://i.imgur.com/jmMTQDQ.png).

Comment: You can also create one **custom** directory role with `microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update` permission for least privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If you put this as an answer, I can accept it. One question though- the app developer member (the SPN which created the app) becomes the owner of the created app. The owner of the app should be able to create secrets. At least that happens with Users (at least in the UI). e.g. if someone assigns me as the Owner of an app in Azure AD, I am able to generate a secret. Shouldn't the same follow for an app?

Comment: The same follow for an app too but that only works if you grant `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission of **Application** type along with Owner access. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76775567/ms-graph-permissions-for-adding-a-oauth-client-secret-are-too-broad/76777342#76777342) for reference.

Comment: alright. Yes, that is what I had to do, as I stated in my answer above. the question was more - why does it need to have that extra permission on top of being an owner , when a normal user like me, can create secrets, as soon as I am made the owner (without any other specific api permissions).